# ruby faye server with scala client

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scala, websocket, faye

I have a Faye server running with ruby, and now, I need to send notifications to a client in Scala, but scala can't handle Bayeux, only WebSockets.
Is there a way to change my connection type from Bayeux to using websockets?
Some conf. files I have

**faye.ru**

```
require 'faye'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

bayeux = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)
run bayeux
```

**sending notifications**

```
 def broadcast(channel, data)
    message = {:channel => channel, :data => data, :ext => {:auth_token => FAYE_TOKEN}}
    uri = URI.parse("http://192.168.0.92:9292/faye")
    Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to think "Scala can't handle Bayeux"? I've never tried it, but a couple of Google searches turn up a handful of potentially useful results for Scala, and many more for Java.

Comment: sorry, when I say scala, I mean Play + Netty...seems like they can't handle this protocol, only 'pure' websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We migrate our scala app to ruby. Much better now :)